# Kubuntu 16.04 LTS - GTX 1060 Nvidia Driver issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

Here's yet another Nvidia driver issue with Ubuntu.

I feel like I've tried everything to get this thing working but haven't had any luck.  A while back I a different setup with Ubuntu 16.04 and I somehow got my GTX1060 working with it.  But then suddenly the screen would freeze and crash after some amount of time.  I was due for a desktop upgrade anyways so I now have the following relevant components with Kubuntu 16.04 LTS:

ASUS Prime X270-A

Intel i7-7700k

Gigabyte GTX 1060 Xtreme

I first installed using the driver downloaded straight from Nvidia.  After the install, it booted to login but the screen became very pixelated and then froze.
I then connected my display to the integrated graphics, entered TTY, purged nvidia and installed from ppa.  Now I'm having the same issue but I can't even make it past the splash screen.  I've tried all kinds of configurations of 'nomodeset quiet splash','nomodeset=0' etc with grub but still not having any luck.

I thought maybe the GPU was bad, but it works and displays fine with the default nouveau drivers.

Any tips and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Nvidia drivers have you installed?

Comment: I've tried nvidia-375,364, 384 and current without any luck

Comment: Probably you tried too much things already and you may have forgot to purge it before installing a new version.

Comment: I made sure to purge before each install.  I just tried out 378 since I saw someone else made it work.  I see the initial splash screen and then there's just giant pixels on the screen and thats it.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Secure boot is disabled.  I feel like I've tried everything suggested on the forums and still can't manage to get it working...

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: No I didn.t  I migrated to Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm now using an MSI GTX 1060 and everything is working just fine.